# Where is "view selected" inside Blender 2.80?

Tags: 3d-view

Do you know inside which menu "view selected" is located in Blender 2.80?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the feature is now called **Frame Selected**

- You can find it in View -> Frame Selected
- The default shorcut is <kbd>.</kbd> on Numpad

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! :)